# Cypress is throwing this error when i try to use custom command: TypeError cy.login is not a function, does someone know how to fix this?

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am working on typescript project, i am trying to write some tests with cypress

I am getting this error: TypeError
cy.login is not a function Because this error occurred during a before each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: Dashboard page when i try to call the custom command cy.login()

this is the custom command

//  support/index.ts

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (email, password) => {
  cy.request("http://localhost:3000/login", {
    email,
    password,
  }).then((r) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("access", r.body.access);
    window.localStorage.setItem("refresh", r.body.refresh);
  });
});
```

// cypress/global.d.ts

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Custom command to select DOM element by data-cy attribute.
       * @example cy.dataCy('greeting')
       */
      dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>;

      // login(email: string, password: string): Chainable<Element>;
      // login(email: string, password: string, loginOptions?: LoginOptions): void;
      login(username: string, password: string): Chainable<string>;
    }
  }
}
```

// cypress/e2e/dashboard.spec.cy.ts

```
describe("Dashboard page", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login("liban.test10@gmail.com", "password");
  });

  it("should actually be accessible", () => {
    cy.visit("/dashboard");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the namespace declaration is done in ****.d.ts*** file type, new *types* "./support" identifiers should be added inside **tsconfig.json** file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "./support"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

By adding "./support" to the tsconfig.json file, it will make the TypeScript lookup a declaration file (the *.d.ts file) inside given directory.

Else the other way is to add:

```
<reference types="../support"/>
```

to every file that requires the new custom command, but this is would be quite repetitive.